Why are the affine parts $Y\cap U_i$ for an projective variety $Y$ open?
I have just started to read Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry and I got a fundamental confusion concerning Corollary 2.3

If $Y$ is a projective variety, then $Y$ is covered by the open sets $Y \cap U_i, i=0,...,n$, which are homeomorphic to affine variets via the mapping $\varphi_i$ defined above.

However, I am confused about why $Y\cap U_i$ is open? $Y$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$ by definition, and we know that $U_i$ is open as complement of the zero set of $x_i$. For $Y\cap U_i$ to be open, its complement has to be closed, i.e. a zero set of a homogeneous polynomial, but how is this clear?
However, since $Y$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$, it follows that $Y\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$ with its induced topology by definition, thus it is homeomorphic to an affine variety (that is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$). Is that correct?

$Y\cap U_i$ is open in $Y$.

As Tabes Bridges says in the comments, $Y\cap U_i$ is open in the topology on $Y \subset \Bbb{P}^n$. Remember that the subspace topology on $Y$ is characterized by the property that $V\subset Y$ is called open if it can be written in the form $U\cap Y$ for $U\subset \Bbb{P}^n$ an open.
